# Define a custom Emacs hook in a generic way

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to run some code after loading my custom file, but I want to do it in a generic fashion. The easy way would be to just have a list of functions that I append to and then execute each function in a list afterwards, but I wanted to see if I could do it as a hook. Something like:

```
(run-hooks 'bw-after-custom-load-hook)
```

and do this each time I want to add to it:

```
(add-hook 'bw-after-custom-load-hook (lambda () 'something))
```

Is this basically how hooks work? All documentation I can find only seems to add stuff to existing hooks provided by modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out (should have tried before posting):

```
;; add my custom hook
(defvar bw-after-custom-load-hook nil
  "Hook called after the custom file is loaded")
```

then in another file:

```
;; but load it after custom has loaded, so it's marked safe
(add-hook 'bw-after-custom-load-hook
      (lambda ()
        (load-theme 'solarized-dark)))
```

then we load custom and call the hook:

```
;; Load custom file last
(setq custom-file (concat dotfiles-dir "custom.el"))
(load custom-file 'noerror)

;; load my custom hooks
(run-hooks 'bw-after-custom-load-hook)
```

Comment: You probably want to accept your own answer, unless you're still looking for input on this?

Comment: Indeed. It wasn't clear to me at first, but hooks in Emacs are *just lists of functions*! (Although there are also some special (clever) rules for handling buffer-local hooks.)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for `after-init-hook`.?

```
(defun my-functions-for-after-init ()
  (....))
```

and then,

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'my-functions-for-after-init)
```